# Azure notification hub - SendGcmNativeNotificationAsync not sending (but test send in azure does)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I've created a notification hub in Azure and when I'm in Azure portal and send a notification with the "test send" option, I received a notification.However
when I sent one via asp.net core Backend API, I got no error but also not sending anything.

```
var notif = "{\"data\" : {\"message\": \"" + model.Message + "\"}}";
bool enableTestSend = true;
NotificationHubClient hub = NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString("endpoint", "test", enableTestSend);

notificationOutcome = await hub.SendGcmNativeNotificationAsync(notif, tag);
var notificationDetails = await hub.GetNotificationOutcomeDetailsAsync(notificationOutcome.NotificationId);
Console.WriteLine(notificationOutcome.State);

foreach (RegistrationResult result in notificationOutcome.Results)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(result.ApplicationPlatform + "\n" + result.RegistrationId + "\n" + result.Outcome);
    }
```

However,notification outcome result also null. I have checked API KEY both at azure portal and firebase. So, where is the missing point? Thanks.